# Cypher - order by rarity of type of child node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have this Cypher query:

```
MATCH (Parent)-[R]-(Child) WHERE ID(Parent)=$parentId
CALL {
    WITH Child
    RETURN apoc.node.degree(Child) as ChildDegree
}
WITH Parent, Child, R, ChildDegree
RETURN Parent, Child, type(R), ChildDegree
ORDER BY R
LIMIT 35
```

Which returns **limited** data (limit is 35). This limit is something which bothers me. Imagine that **Parent** has this **Children**:

- 40 x **A**
- 3 x **B**
- 2 x **C**

In this situation my query sometimes returns **(35 x A)**. What I'd like to achieve is to make this query order by the rarest type of child for this parent and for this example return this data:

- 2 x **C**
- 3 x **B**
- 30 x **A**

Answer (score 0):

I tested below query using the Movie database.

- Collect parent, child, R and child degree and put all child degree in a list (collect_nodes)
- Create a range of index to accumulate the sum of child degrees (range_idx)
- From 0 to the number of rows, get a running sum of degrees
- From each parent, child, R and child degree, check if sum_degree <= 35
- Return the parent, child, R and child degree

You cannot get the exact rows that equals 35 because what you limit is the number of rows and not the child degrees.  Also, show us sample data to work on so that we can give you the best answer

```
MATCH (Parent)-[R]-(Child) WHERE ID(Parent)=$parentId
CALL {
    WITH Child
    RETURN apoc.node.degree(Child) as ChildDegree
}
WITH Parent, Child, type(R) as R, ChildDegree ORDER BY R, ChildDegree
WITH collect({p:Parent, c:Child, r: R, cd:ChildDegree }) as collect_nodes, collect(ChildDegree) as collect_degs
WITH collect_nodes, collect_degs, RANGE(0, SIZE(collect_degs)-1) AS range_idx
UNWIND range_idx as idx
WITH collect_nodes[idx] as nodes, REDUCE(acc = 0, value in (collect_degs[idx] + collect_degs[..idx]) | acc + value) AS sum_degree
UNWIND nodes as n_set
WITH n_set.p as Parent, n_set.c as Child, n_set.r as R, n_set.cd as ChildDegree WHERE sum_degree <= 35
RETURN Parent, Child, R, ChildDegree
```

Sample result:

```
╒═══════════════════════════╤══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╤══════════╤═════════════╕
│"Parent"                   │"Child"                                                               │"R"       │"ChildDegree"│
╞═══════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╪══════════╪═════════════╡
│{"name":"Jessica Thompson"}│{"name":"Paul Blythe"}                                                │"FOLLOWS" │2            │
├───────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┤
│{"name":"Jessica Thompson"}│{"name":"James Thompson"}                                             │"FOLLOWS" │3            │
├───────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┤
│{"name":"Jessica Thompson"}│{"name":"Angela Scope"}                                               │"FOLLOWS" │3            │
├───────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┤
│{"name":"Jessica Thompson"}│{"tagline":"Come as you are","title":"The Birdcage","released":1996}  │"REVIEWED"│5            │
├───────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┤
│{"name":"Jessica Thompson"}│{"tagline":"It's a hell of a thing, killing a man","title":"Unforgiven│"REVIEWED"│5            │
│                           │","released":1992}                                                    │          │             │
├───────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┤
│{"name":"Jessica Thompson"}│{"tagline":"Break The Codes","title":"The Da Vinci Code","released":20│"REVIEWED"│7            │
│                           │06}                                                                   │          │             │
├───────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┤
│{"name":"Jessica Thompson"}│{"tagline":"Pain heals, Chicks dig scars... Glory lasts forever","titl│"REVIEWED"│8            │
│                           │e":"The Replacements","released":2000}                                │          │             │
└───────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────┴─────────────┘
```

Comment: What is the running sum of degrees and `sum_degree < 35` condition? I just wanted nodes to be sorted by the rarest type. Rarest meaning - if node has this children: `[A,A,B,C,C,C,C,D,E,F]' then I would expect this query to return them in this order `[B,D,E,F,A,A,C,C,C,C]`

Comment: Create me a sample dataset with this scenario then I will help you. Look at some examples in neo4j website on hiw to create sample data